# iOS - How to animate (dis)appereance of scope bar in UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, searchbar

Well I read [this](http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=418) article, however the scope bar just shows instantly, no animation.

Comment: are you adding the uisearchbar from Interface Builder or programatically?

Comment: i think it's better to add it programatically, by the way, show your code, it's difficult to understand your error this way.

Comment: also have a look at this answer:https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1652157?threadID=1652157&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
     searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;  
    return YES;
    }

    - (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [searchBar sizeToFit];  
     searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;  
    return YES;
    }
```

Remember to associate the UISearchBar delegate.

Comment: Hmmm, this is supposed to animate scope bar?